# Proving $\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}<\frac{\tan\beta-\tan\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}<\frac{1}{\cos^2\beta}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Prove: $$\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}<\frac{\tan\beta-\tan\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}<\frac{1}{\cos^2\beta} \\ \forall 0<\alpha<\beta<\frac\pi2 $$

Well for starters I noticed that this is basically squeeze theorem for derving $\tan x$ since the middle looks like the defintion of deriviation and both left and right sides are the derviation of $\tan x$.

Now to formaly prove it,

$$(\tan\alpha)'<(\tan(\beta-\alpha))'<(\tan\beta)'$$

Then by the next step we get to the given equation and that's it (?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Lagrange Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) theorem. Define $f(x)= \tan x$. The theorem states that, $\frac{\tan \beta - \tan \alpha}{\beta - \alpha} = \frac{1}{\cos^2(c)}$. $\alpha < c < \beta$ implies $\cos\beta < \cos c < \cos\alpha$ implies $\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha} < \frac{1}{\cos^2c} < \frac{1}{\cos^2\beta}$

Answer (score 4):

Lagrange's theorem:

$$f(x)=\tan x,\: x\in (0,\: \frac{\pi}{2})$$

We have $$\frac{f(\alpha)-f(\beta)}{\alpha-\beta}=f'(c )=\frac{1}{\cos^2c},\: \text{with}\: c\in [\alpha,\: \beta]$$

Because $$\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}\leq f'(c )=\frac{1}{\cos^2c}\leq \frac{1}{\cos^2\beta}\: \: \text{Q.E.D}$$

Answer (score 2):

By Lagrange's theorem we have some $\gamma\in(\alpha,\beta)$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{\cos^2\gamma}=\frac{\tan\beta-\tan\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}
$$
Now it is remains to recall that $\cos$ is a decreasing positive function on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}
]$